# Sending Notification for Azure DevOps builds to specific sub-teams

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

When running our pipeline, we have an (manual) input parameter that determines for which subscription the build is going to deploy.

I know there are some notification options inside Azure DevOps, however, they do not seem to allow you to differentiate on the basis of input parameters which alert is triggered, only the name of the pipeline ('Definition name'), which in our case remains the same.

We could build some custom code that selects e.g. a specific webhook on the basis of the input parameter, however, it would seem maybe that Azure DevOps build in notification can do this more easily.

Does anybody know if, on the basis of a manual user input parameter, the notifications for the build can be send to different teams/email addresses?

[image]

(Played around with the options shown in the image & atm we are not using releases only 'regular' pipelines)